# Multiple stations connection in Ticket to Ride Europe

Tags: ticket-to-ride, ticket-to-ride-europe

In Ticket to Ride: Europe
Can I build multiple consecutive stations on my opponent's route?
In other words, can my two stations connect to each other?

An example, to make it more clear.
[image: Paris to Edinburgh]
I have a route to Amsterdam, but from there to London and to Edinburgh my opponent
(2 players only) built a route.
Can I put a station on Amsterdam and one on London to connect to Edinburgh?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you may use multiple borrowed routes to complete a destination ticket. There is simply no limit in the rules.

Comment: Can you add a source to this, please?

Comment: You're asking me to prove that there is no limit in the rules. I can't prove that something doesn't exist. I can't give a source because the rules don't say "there is no limit". They simply don't mention a limit. All they say is that a station allows you use to borrow a route to complete tickets.

Comment: The official digital version doesn't impose any limit.

Comment: Thank you for your time and answer, and for the additional explanation too.

Answer (score 3):

The rules do not state that you cannot use more than one station claimed route to complete a ticket.  Therefore, you may use more than one station claimed route to complete a ticket.

This will require two stations.  Each station can only claim the use of a single route.